# Xcode 8 Beta 4 CGColor.components unavailable

Tags: core-graphics, swift3

Whilst the code below worked previously, it has stopped working in Xcode 8 Beta 4, presumably because the `components` return was a very un-Swift-y C-array of floats, and has been removed. The error is bald - "'components' is unavailable" - and I can't find what has replaced it, if anything. Does anyone know how to produce the same functionality?

```
public var cgColour: CGColor {
    get {
        return CGColor(red: self.colourRed, green: self.colourGreen, blue: self.colourBlue, alpha: self.colourAlpha)
    }
    set {
        let comps = newValue.components // No longer available
        self.colourRed = (comps?[0])!
        self.colourGreen = (comps?[1])!
        self.colourBlue = (comps?[2])!
        self.colourAlpha = (comps?[3])!
    }
}
```

**Update**
@Hamish's answer works, but my original intent was not to use UIColor nor NSColor so that my code works in both iOS & MacOS. What I've ended up doing is this...

```
#if os(iOS)
import UIKit
#elseif os(OSX)
import Cocoa
#endif

extension CGColor {
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        #if os(iOS)
            UIColor(cgColor: self).getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        #elseif os(OSX)
            NSColor(cgColor: self)?.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        #endif
        return (r, g, b, a)
    }
}
// Playground code to test...
#if os(iOS)
let rgba = UIColor.brown.cgColor.components //(0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0)
#elseif os(OSX)
let rgba = NSColor.brown.cgColor.components //(0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 1.0)
#endif
```

... this is *such* a kludge - has anyone got a better answer?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcolor

Comment: Excellent idea - but actually CIColor is a better call, as SKColor has no direct init from CGColor, and CIColor has, and also has `.red`, `.green`, `.blue` & `.alpha` properties. Do you want to make that the answer?

Comment: @LeoDabus The only problem with `SKColor` is that it's just a typealias, so AFAIK you cannot use it work around the fact that `NSColor`'s `init?(cgColor:)` is failable, and `UIColor`'s `init(cgColor:)` isn't. Therefore you'd still end up with having to use a conditional compilation statement (one with an optional chain, one without). `CIColor` definitely looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Hamish's answer works, but my original intent was *not* to use `UIColor` or `NSColor` so that my code works in both iOS & MacOS. @LeoDabus suggested using `SKColor`, but that's just a type alias to either `NSColor` or `UIColor`, and doesn't have a direct init from `CGColor` anyway, however, Leo's suggestion prompted me to refine my kludge using **`CIColor`** instead:

```
import CoreImage

extension CGColor {
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let ciColor = CIColor(cgColor: self)
        return (ciColor.red, ciColor.green, ciColor.blue, ciColor.alpha)
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the best solution (+1) – although IMO still feels a little unsatisfactory having to wrap the `CGColor` in another instance just to access the color components. I would hope that Apple is working on a better interface to get the color components from the `CGColor` directly, but I guess we'll have to wait and see what (if anything) Xcode 8 beta 5 brings.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a transitional beta issue.

The Swift repo on Github includes an [extensive SDK overlay for CoreGraphics](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1206387c3c6ca09a0bfa73a77e096811a5751e2/stdlib/public/SDK/CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.swift), including a new version of `CGColor.components` whose return type is a Swift array instead of an `UnsafePointer`. Part of how they make that SDK overlay work is [API notes](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1206387c3c6ca09a0bfa73a77e096811a5751e2/apinotes/CoreGraphics.apinotes), which map some of the underlying C calls to double-underscore'd Swift methods so that the overlay can wrap them in a more-Swifty interface.

It looks like the beta 4 and beta 5 compilers picked up the API notes change, but not the overlay that includes the new version of `components`. Presumably a future beta (or the final Swift 3.0 / Xcode 8.0 release) will include everything that's now on github.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also a little perplexed as to why they have removed the `components` property from `CGColor`, as there doesn't seem to be any kind of obvious replacement method/property. <del>It looks like they're trying to get people to use the higher level `UIColor` or `NSColor` classes instead.</del> (As [@rickster has discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834798/2976878), this looks more like a simple transitional issue).

One solution, as you're working with RGB colors, would be to simply wrap your `CGColor` in a `UIColor`/`NSColor`, and then use the [`getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/getRed:green:blue:alpha:) method to get out the components instead.

```
public var cgColour : CGColor {
    get {
        return CGColor(red: colourRed, green: colourGreen, blue: colourBlue, alpha: colourAlpha)
    }
    set {
        NSColor(cgColor: newValue)?.getRed(&colourRed, green: &colourGreen, blue: &colourBlue, alpha: &colourAlpha)
    }
}
```

Perhaps not the most ideal solution – would certainly be interested to know if anyone else has a better one, or knows more about this change. Depending on the usage of this property, you may also want to consider simply making it of type `UIColor`/`NSColor` to prevent the needless wrapping that this solution requires.

Comment: Hmm. The reason I'm using CGColor (indeed Core Graphics generally) is to have platform agnostic code...

Comment: @Grimxn Ah okay... I'm not sure I can offer you a platform agnostic solution – as this change doesn't appear to be well (if at all!) documented. I'll leave my answer here in case it's useful to anyone else and hope that someone else comes up with a better idea :)

Comment: I've unaccepted your answer temporarily to see if anyone else answers... sorry!

Comment: @Grimxn No problem, I would also be interested to see if anyone has a better solution :)

Comment: I just ran into this same thing when porting a lib over. I don't have another solution, but just wanted to say thank you to @Hamish for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaking something, but you can find this in the imported header of CGColor.

```
/* Return the color components (including alpha) associated with `color'. */

@available(OSX 10.3, *)
public var __unsafeComponents: UnsafePointer<CGFloat>? { get }
```

Isn't this what you are looking for?

I can write something like this:

```
public var cgColour: CGColor {
    get {
        return CGColor(red: self.colourRed, green: self.colourGreen, blue: self.colourBlue, alpha: self.colourAlpha)
    }
    set {
        if let comps = newValue.__unsafeComponents, newValue.numberOfComponents == 4 {
            self.colourRed = comps[0]
            self.colourGreen = comps[1]
            self.colourBlue = comps[2]
            self.colourAlpha = comps[3]
        }
    }
}
```

It works as I expect, but I'm not sure it's as you expect, or Apple would treat this as using a private API. ([Apple's latest documentation of `CGColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcolor) does not contain double-underscore leaded symbols.)

Comment: It rather looks like it!

Answer (score -3):

```html
extension UIColor {
    var all4Components:(red:CGFloat, green:CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha:CGFloat) {
    let components = self.cgColor.components!
    let red = components[0]
    let green = components[1]
    let blue = components[2]
    let alpha = components[3]
    return (red:red, green:green, blue: blue, alpha:alpha)

    }
}
```