# Swift 3 unresolved identifier CGColorGetComponents

Tags: uicolor, swift3, cgcolor

How can I refactor this code in Swift 3?:

```
    extension UIColor {
        var hexString: String {
            // Produces "Use of unresolved identifier 'CGColorGetComponents'"
            let components = CGColorGetComponents(self.cgColor)
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's supposed to be `cgColor.components`, although this won't work as of Xcode 8 beta 4, [see this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769322/xcode-8-beta-4-cgcolor-components-unavailable) for more info.

Comment: You can use getRed method apple-reference-documentation://hsPr9ZXOsl

Answer (score 2):

```
var r:CGFloat = 0, g:CGFloat = 0, b:CGFloat = 0, a:CGFloat = 0
self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b:, alpha: &a)
...
```