# replace property CGColorGetComponents (unavailable in swift 4) in a random color array

Tags: ios, swift

how can I replace CGColorGetComponents property (unavailable in swift 4) in this random color array?

```
fileprivate func hexyColor(color: UIColor) -> String {

    let components = CGColorGetComponents(color.cgColor)
    var hex = ""

    for i in 0...2 {
        let int = Int(components[i] * 255)
        let hexCode = String(int, radix: 16)

        if hexCode.count < 2 {
            hex = hex + "0\(hexCode)"
        } else {
            hex = hex + hexCode
        }
    }

    return "#\(hex)"
}
```

thx in advance for reply :)

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899725/swift-3-unresolved-identifier-cgcolorgetcomponents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been renamed so just use

```
let components = color.cgColor.components
```